Accessing Profile URL from API while signing in with linkedin
I want to access the url of user signing in with linkedin in my application. I am trying to find r_liteprofile access, but couldn't find that permission in my developer dashboard.
Tried accessing API Endpoint - https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
But responds
{ "serviceErrorCode": 100, "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me", "status": 403 }
Also tried finding r_liteprofile on my dashboard, but couldn't find.
